# Raspberry Pi 1B, mjpg-streamer and USB web camera

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, webcam, raspbian

I'm using the latest `Raspbian Jessie (2016-05-27)` and `Raspberry Pi 1 Model B (512 Mb)`. I'm trying to stream video through `Logitec C270 (usb web cam)` and [mjpg-streamer](https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer).

I followed instructions [here](https://miguelmota.com/blog/raspberry-pi-camera-board-video-streaming/), but it does not work for me.
I'm using the following command to start streaming server and tried different combinations with resolution and frames per second:

```
/usr/local/bin/mjpg_streamer -i "/usr/local/lib/input_uvc.so -n" -o "/usr/local/lib/output_http.so -p 8888 -w /usr/local/www" &
```

After that the server is not starting at all. Soon I realised that new kernel requires a [patch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=751735#p751735):
`nano input_uvc_patch`

```
    --- plugins/input_uvc/input_uvc.c       (revision 174)
+++ plugins/input_uvc/input_uvc.c       (working copy)
@@ -405,9 +405,13 @@
         if(pcontext->videoIn->formatIn == V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUYV) {
             DBG("compressing frame from input: %d\n", (int)pcontext->id);
             pglobal->in[pcontext->id].size = compress_yuyv_to_jpeg(pcontext->videoIn, pglobal->in[pcontext->id].buf, pcontext->videoIn->framesizeIn, gquality);
+            /* copy this frame's timestamp to user space */
+            pglobal->in[pcontext->id].timestamp = pcontext->videoIn->buf.timestamp;
         } else {
             DBG("copying frame from input: %d\n", (int)pcontext->id);
-            pglobal->in[pcontext->id].size = memcpy_picture(pglobal->in[pcontext->id].buf, pcontext->videoIn->tmpbuffer, pcontext->videoIn->buf.bytesused);
+            pglobal->in[pcontext->id].size = memcpy_picture(pglobal->in[pcontext->id].buf, pcontext->videoIn->tmpbuffer, pcontext->videoIn->tmpbytesused);
+            /* copy this frame's timestamp to user space */
+            pglobal->in[pcontext->id].timestamp = pcontext->videoIn->tmptimestamp;
         }

 #if 0
@@ -418,8 +422,6 @@
         prev_size = global->size;
 #endif

-        /* copy this frame's timestamp to user space */
-        pglobal->in[pcontext->id].timestamp = pcontext->videoIn->buf.timestamp;

         /* signal fresh_frame */
         pthread_cond_broadcast(&pglobal->in[pcontext->id].db_update);
Index: plugins/input_uvc/v4l2uvc.c
===================================================================
--- plugins/input_uvc/v4l2uvc.c (revision 174)
+++ plugins/input_uvc/v4l2uvc.c (working copy)
@@ -450,6 +450,8 @@
         */

         memcpy(vd->tmpbuffer, vd->mem[vd->buf.index], vd->buf.bytesused);
+        vd->tmpbytesused = vd->buf.bytesused;
+        vd->tmptimestamp = vd->buf.timestamp;

         if(debug)
             fprintf(stderr, "bytes in used %d \n", vd->buf.bytesused);
Index: plugins/input_uvc/v4l2uvc.h
===================================================================
--- plugins/input_uvc/v4l2uvc.h (revision 174)
+++ plugins/input_uvc/v4l2uvc.h (working copy)
@@ -28,6 +28,7 @@


 #include <stdio.h>
+#include <stdint.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
@@ -105,6 +106,8 @@
     int framecount;
     int recordstart;
     int recordtime;
+    uint32_t tmpbytesused;
+    struct timeval tmptimestamp;
 };
```

`patch -p0 < input_uvc_patch`
`make USE_LIBV4L2=true clean all`
`sudo make install`

After that the server was up and the LED on camera blinked for a few seconds. Then I've got the following errors:

[image]

Full trace:

```
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.624402] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.758195] Process systemd-udevd (pid: 116, stack limit = 0xda5ae188)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.766538] Stack: (0xda5afd58 to 0xda5b0000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.772716] fd40:                                                       00000142 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.784357] fd60: da539000 da5afd8c da5afd84 da5afd78 d6956800 da539000 da5afdb4 da5afd88

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.795970] fd80: c04c5000 c04ab53c 00000008 7fffffff da539000 da5aff4c da539000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.807600] fda0: 00000142 dbb5c6a4 da5afe14 da5afdb8 c04c5598 c04c4f84 da5afe50 da5afdc4

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.819330] fdc0: 0000000c da5afe50 da5aff4c 00000008 00000000 da480d00 00000000 00000074

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.831231] fde0: 00000000 00000000 c047b83c da5aff4c 00000000 00000000 daa11000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.843342] fe00: da5afe30 00000000 da5afe24 da5afe18 c047b3b8 c04c5288 da5aff34 da5afe28

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.855608] fe20: c047ba70 c047b3a0 c01057dc 00000000 da5f6020 da47b934 192253cf 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.868069] fe40: da5afe6c da5afe50 c006634c 00000000 beeeaed4 00000028 80840fb8 0000011a

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.880651] fe60: da5afe8c 00000000 daa11840 c0107e24 80841fc0 da5b3680 da5afea4 da5affb0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.893334] fe80: da5b3680 0000081f 80841fc0 da47b900 00000010 dbb5c6a4 00000000 da5afea8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.906203] fea0: c0573cdc c0053218 00000000 fffffff5 00000000 beeeaef4 00000008 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.919120] fec0: 00000000 00000000 00000800 00000008 da5afeb4 c0823ae4 0000081f c0573b44

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.932037] fee0: 80841fc0 da5affb0 00001000 00003038 da5affac da5aff00 c0009204 c0146dfc

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.944971] ff00: da5aff1c da5aff10 c0146dfc c0146d68 daa11000 00000000 beeeaeb8 00000128

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.957905] ff20: c000f9e8 da5ae000 da5aff94 da5aff38 c047c7cc c047b8a0 00000000 00000001

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.970831] ff40: 7f6428c4 00000000 fffffff7 da5afe90 0000000c 00000001 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.983741] ff60: da5afe60 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 beeeaeb8 beeeaeb8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  150.996677] ff80: b6fddf10 00000000 da5affa4 da5aff98 c047c814 c047c78c 00000000 da5affa8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  151.009618] ffa0: c000f820 c047c808 beeeaeb8 b6fddf10 00000004 beeeaeb8 00000000 0000000c

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  151.022541] ffc0: beeeaeb8 b6fddf10 00000000 00000128 8083cb34 0000011a 808330c0 80840fb8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  151.035446] ffe0: 00000000 beeeae94 7f61a388 b6f6d37c 60000010 00000004 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:24 ...
 kernel:[  151.136256] Code: 1a000025 e59030b0 e3530000 0a00001b (e593400c)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  151.810011] Internal error: Oops: 1 [#2] ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  151.948402] Process systemd-udevd (pid: 748, stack limit = 0xd894a188)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  151.956749] Stack: (0xd894be78 to 0xd894c000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  151.962924] be60:                                                       00000000 d69568d4

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  151.974593] be80: c0876ce8 d6956800 d894beac d894be98 c04827e4 c0481bb0 00000000 fffffffe

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  151.986212] bea0: d894bef4 d894beb0 c04c49f8 c04827c8 c0107dd0 d782d160 d88a2a80 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  151.997855] bec0: 00000000 da619f20 da619f20 d782d160 00000000 d782d180 dad11010 d7871b28

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  152.009585] bee0: d782d180 00000008 d894bf0c d894bef8 c047a6ec c04c47e4 d6966f00 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  152.021489] bf00: d894bf1c d894bf10 c047a790 c047a6c8 d894bf5c d894bf20 c012dcdc c047a780

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  152.033629] bf20: 00000000 00000000 c0109c64 d6966f08 d6966f00 d8869f48 d8869b40 c0889f90

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  152.045938] bf40: 00000000 c000f9e8 d894a000 00000000 d894bf6c d894bf60 c012de88 c012dc50

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  152.058412] bf60: d894bf8c d894bf70 c003b2b0 c012de7c 00000004 d894a000 c000f9e8 d894bfb0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  152.070976] bf80: d894bfac d894bf90 c0013524 c003b244 8083cb28 00000000 7f660004 00000006

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  152.083616] bfa0: 00000000 d894bfb0 c000f848 c0013450 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  152.096453] bfc0: 8083cb28 00000000 7f660004 00000006 beeeaaf8 7f66000c 8083cb28 80833008

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  152.109361] bfe0: 00000000 beeea93c 7f62de58 b6f6cd3c 60000010 0000000c 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul 29 19:16:25 ...
 kernel:[  152.225862] Code: e5963008 e3a01000 e2433001 e5863008 (e894000c)
```

Can anybody explain me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was too low power for Raspberry Pi. So, it's not problem with Raspberry Pi or mjpg_streamer.